# Performance of mutable versus immutable objects

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa

I would like to ask all the Cocoa veterans out there - is there any **difference in performance** between using mutable versus immutable objects in cases like:

- `NSString`'s `stringByAppendingString:` versus `NSMutableString`'s `appendString:`
- `NSArray`'s `arrayByAddingObject:` versus `NSMutableArray`'s `addObject:`
- ...

Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: Make a log with timestamp before and after each mutable and immutable method call and you can see for yourself which is faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is hard to answer : `NSArray` and `NSString` aren't actual implementations, they are class-clusters and so are `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableString`. The true implementations underneath can't be determined and thus performances would be hard to compare.
You probably won't find a definite answer to that one.

But what I would *guess* is : `stringByAppendingString` and `arrayByAddingObject` create new objects which contains the modifications, *ie* copy the current items to a new place in memory, `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableString` should have better performances because they are built to prevent copying when possible (not actually true because `NSMutableArray` might recopy memory when elements are added but not every time).

I think you should trust the CoreFoundation coders on this one : you wan't to mutate objects ? Use the mutables one.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you very much, this is exactly what I wanted to know.